How to change the color of the "highlight" (border when focused) of an ion-input with Ionic 7?
I am trying to change the color of what seems to be called the highlight of an ion-input. It basically is a border that appears when the input is focused (see picture below).


The second image is the input focused. As you can see, it is blue by default, but I would like it orange.
I could handle the blue line, but for this particular input, I need to link the value to a variable in the typescript. For this I am using [(ngModel)] like this:
<ion-input placeholder="Placeholder" [(ngModel)]="name_of_variable"></ion-input>
But this raises a new problem: the color of the hightlight changes to green !

I can't find the reason of this change.
Do you have any idea on how to solve one of these two problems ?
I tried different css properties:
--color, --border-color, --border-color-focused, --highlight-color, --highlight-color-focused.
None of them have worked, neither have regular css border properties.
EDIT : Example of code
My html:
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">

    <ion-input placeholder="test" [(ngModel)]="test"></ion-input>
  
</ion-content>

My TS:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonicModule, CommonModule, FormsModule],
})
export class HomePage {
  test: String = "";

  constructor() {}

}

The resulting element when focused:

SOLUTION:
The CSS/ionic property --highlight-color-valid works for this (while --highlight-color-focused does not for a reason).
Thanks to @StackoverBlows for the solution !

Hi, Can you share some more code related to this?

I have added an example of my code in the Edit section :)

I am assuming that you have added some code that is making the color of border to orange and then green, can you add that css as well?

Ionic uses shadow-dom, the docs have shadow dom variables you can use. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#css-custom-properties-1

@StackoverBlows I don't know how I have not seen this and tested everything before. For some reason, --highlight-color-focused does not work, but --highlight-color-valid works. A fix is a fix lol. Thank you very much for the link !

You're welcome! You can also try to add !important to the end of the line: --highlight-color-focused: red !important;

.input-fill-outline.has-focus.sc-ion-input-md-h {
--border-color: #ffc409; (Set color what you need)
}
